# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x184f (unknown) for fragment DiscDispFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

DiscFragment.java : (**Updated**)

```
public class DiscFragment extends DagFragment {
//    @BindView(R.id.dispFrag)
//    LinearLayout discDispLayout;

@BindView(R.id.get_button)
Button getButton;

@NonNull
@Override
public String getFragmentTitle(@NonNull Context context) {
    return context.getString(R.string.ex_disp);
}

@OnClick(R.id.getbutton)
void onGetClicked() {
    DiscDispFragment fragment = new DiscDispFragment();
    FragmentManager fmt = getChildFragmentManager();
    if (fmt != null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fmt.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.discover, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}

@Override
protected int getFragmentLayout() {
    return R.layout.get_started;
}
```

}

DiscDispFragment.java :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(getFragmentLayout(), container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
    return rootView;
}
@Override
    protected int getFragmentLayout() {
        return R.layout.dispFragment;
    }
```

dispFragment.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="?attr/background_color"
    android:layoutDirection="locale"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dispFrag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="750dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/progress_bar_small"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar_small"
            android:background="?attr/bg_color"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/st_away"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/st_close" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/st_to"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="151dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background"
            android:text="@string/st_to"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/pad_12"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/progress_bar"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/element_margin"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:progressBackgroundTint="#606067"
            android:progressTint="#8e8e93" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/disp_state_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/element_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/element_margin"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/element_margin"
            android:text="@string/progress_message"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/st_size" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_error_action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/element_margin"
            android:background="@color/butn_background"
            android:padding="@dimen/butn_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            tools:text="@string/hello" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/discays"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_discovered_display_item" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

get_started.xml : (**Updated**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/des_get_started"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="675dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="51dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sheet_image"
            android:layout_width="232dp"
            android:layout_height="177dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/disp_name"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/im"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sheet_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/st_away"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/darktheme"
            android:textSize="@dimen/s21"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sheet_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/st_desc"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black_darktheme"
            android:textSize="@dimen/s_21" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/get_started_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/get_started_background"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/get_started_button"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/discover"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Exception :

```
2020-09-23 20:00:23.509 4897-4897/com.misc.dd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.misc.dd, PID: 4897
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x184f (unknown) for fragment DiscDispFragment{58583d9} (17f05957-c8f3-4a58-9405-0f7ef88f401d) id=0x184f}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:315)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Can you include your `R.layout.get_started`?

Comment: @OnClick(R2.id.getbutton) what is R2

Comment: @ianhanniballake : Have updated in the question section.

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri : Thats a typo

Comment: So where is the `R.id.dispFrag` declared that you're trying to use with `fragmentTransaction.replace`? I'm not seeing it in your `R.layout.get_started`

Comment: @ianhanniballake : That's in the dispFragment.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```
DiscDispFragment fragment = new DiscDispFragment();
FragmentManager fmt = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fmt.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.dispFrag, fragment);
```

What you're saying is that you want:

1. To create a new `DiscDispFragment` instance
2. Using the `getChildFragmentManager()` means you want the new Fragment to be fully contained within the parent fragment's view - in this case, your `DiscFragment`'s `getting_started` layout
3. Replace any existing Fragment in the `R.id.dispFrag` container with your new `DiscDispFragment`, adding the `DiscDispFragment`'s layout to that container.

The reason you're getting an error is that `R.id.dispFrag` is **not** a `FrameLayout` or other `ViewGroup` within your `DiscFragment`'s layout.

To solve this, you have a couple of options:

- If you actually do want your `DiscDispFragment` as a child Fragment of `DiscFragment`, then you need to add a `FrameLayout` or `FragmentContainerView` to its layout which is where your `DiscDispFragment` will be added to.
- If you don't want `DiscDispFragment` to be a child fragment, then you need to *not* use `getChildFragmentManager()`. `requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` would be the activity's FragmentManager (where you'd use a container ID in the Activity's layout) or you'd use `getParentFragmentManager()`/`getFragmentManager()` (depending on what version of Fragments you're using) to access the same `FragmentManager` that you added `DiscFragment` to (where you'd use whatever container ID you originally added `DiscFragment` to).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I could understand very well. I choose the option 1 you mentioned. 1. Created a framelayout with id "discover" in the layout of the DiscFragment and called passed the framelayout id as the containerViewId, to which the DiscDispFragment would be added to, but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: @OnClick(R2.id.getbutton)
    void onGetClicked() {
        DiscDispFragment fragment = new DiscDispFragment();
        FragmentManager fmt = getChildFragmentManager();
        if (fmt != null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fmt.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R2.id.discover, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }

Comment: get_started.xml :     
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/discover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include your updated `get_started` layout and your updated code?

Comment: Have updated the code DiscFragment.java, get_started.xml above. Please have a look.

Comment: It was something to do with the R.id.discover parameter I passed. The above change worked. Thanks a lot for the valuable answer. It helped me at the much needed time. Thanks a lot.